# Punctured open set is not contractible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be an open subset, and let $x\in U$. Then $U\setminus\{x\}$ is not contractible. A space $X$ is called contractible if the identity map on $X$  is homotopic to a constant map $X\to X$. So, I have to show that $Id_{U\setminus\{x\}}$ can not be homotopic to a constant map. What are tools to show that maps are not homotopic?

Comment: Do you know about fundamental groups or homology groups ?

Comment: We have only treated fundamental groups

Comment: @James Excellent. Then take any base point in the punctured space and any closed path *around the point* $\;x\;$ . That path cannot be "deformed" to a point and thus the Fund. Group isn't trivial.

Comment: contractible implies simply connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fundamental groups to solve this, here's a way :

Find a small open ball $B$ centered at $x$ included in $U$ ($U$ is open, so that exists).

Prove that if $y\in B\setminus\{x\}$, then the map induced by the inclusion $\pi_1(B\setminus\{x\}, y)\to \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x\}, y)$ is non zero.
This will use some knowledge of the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{x\}$ and thus of $S^1$.

Prove that this map factors through $\pi_1(U\setminus\{x\}, y)$, and conclude.

Note that when you learn about higher homotopy groups, you will be able to adapt this proof to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: What do you mean with, "The induced inclusion is non zero"?  If $[\gamma]\neq 0$, then $i_*([\gamma])=[i\circ\gamma]\neq 0$? Could you add some details?

Comment: The map induced by the inclusion. And no I didn't say injective (well actually it will be), it just means it's not rhe zero map. You could prove that it's actually an isomorphism if that's easier for you (it is true)

Comment: I don't really get what you mean

Comment: The inclusion $(B\setminus\{x\},y)\to (\mathbb{R}^2,y)$ induces a morphism on $\pi_1$. The point is to prove that it's not the $0$ morphism; or if you can, prove that it's an isomorphism

Comment: I have shown that $\pi_1(B\setminus\{x\})\cong\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x\},y)$, how can I conclude that this maps factors through $\pi_1(U\setminus\{x\},y)?$

Comment: What is the map that induces the isomorphism you mention ?

Comment: I retract $R^2\setminus\{x\}$ on $B\setminus\{x\}$ tot a closed ball $B$.

Comment: Ok, can you describe the inverse map then ?

Comment: Do I need that for a retraction?

Comment: What is your definition of retraction ?

Comment: Let $A\subseteq X$ be a subspace, then a retraction is a continuous map $r: X \to A$ with $r|_{A}=Id_A$, $r(X)=A$. By a proposition in Hatcher's, if such a retraction exists, then the induced homomorphism by the inclusion is injective. Since $U\setminus\{x\}$ retracts onto $B\setminus\{x\}$, and $\pi_1(B\setminus\{x\})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, $U\setminus\{x\}$ has non-trivial fundamental group, hence is not retractible.

Comment: It's not clear that $U\setminus\{x\}$ retracts onto $B$; however you finally wrote the words I wanted you to write : "the morphism induced by the inclusion"